# TechTalk.SpecFlow.BindingException: Ambiguous step definitions found for step

Tags: c#, automated-tests, cucumber, specflow, gherkin

I have 2 features that use the same Given step and pass a username `Given I navigate to the HomePage with the <user>`

When I try to run a test I get the following:

`TechTalk.SpecFlow.BindingException: 'Ambiguous step definitions found for step 'Given I navigate to the SourceForge HomePage with the user1`

Feature 1:

```
Feature: UploadProjectFileFeature
    In order to to be to add project documentation
    I want to be able to upload project file(s) to the correct project repository
@mytag
Scenario: Upload Project File(S) to the correct project repository
    Given I navigate to the HomePage with the <user>
    And I Log into the application with <username> and <password>
    When I navigate to the <project> page and I upload File(s)
    Then the file should upload successfully

    Examples:
        | user  | username | password     | project         |
        | user1 | username | Passtest.123 | TestAutomationP |
```

Feature 2:

```
Feature: UserLogin
    In order to access my account
    As a user of the website
   I want to log into the website

@mytag1
Scenario: Successful Login with Correct user
    Given I navigate to the HomePage with the <user>
    And I Navigate to the LoginPage
    When I Log into the application with <username> and <password>
    And I Navigate to the Profile Page
    Then <user> and <username> should be displayed correctly


    Examples:
    | user  | username| password     |
    | user1| username| Passtest.123 |
```

I tried to create a base class and then use tags and virtual and override as a work around but I keep getting the same error

BaseClass:

```
  public  class FeatureBaseClass
    {
        
        [Given(@"I navigate to the HomePage with (.*)")]
        public virtual void GivenINavigateToTheSourceForgeHomePageWith(string user)
        {
   
            string User = user;
        }
```

Tests:

```
    [Binding]
  [Scope(Feature = "UserLogin")]
    public class UserLogin : FeatureBaseClass
    {
        
       
        [Given(@"I navigate to the HomePage with (.*)")]
    [Scope(Feature = "UserLogin", Scenario = "Successful Login with Correct user")]
    public override void GivenINavigateToTheSourceForgeHomePageWith(string user)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Launched Browser with " + user);
 
        }
```

```
    [Binding]
   [Scope(Feature = "UploadProjectFileFeature")]
    public class UploadProjectFile : FeatureBaseClass
    {
      
        [Given(@"I navigate to the HomePage with (.*)")]
        [Scope(Feature = "UploadProjectFileFeature", Scenario = "Upload Project File(S) to the correct project repository")]
        public  override void GivenINavigateToTheSourceForgeHomePageWith(string user)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Launched Browser with " + user);
            
 
        }
```

Can anyone see where I am going wrong? or can anyone suggest a better solution?

Comment: Yes this was the post i followed to come up with my solution. But was unsuccessfully able to replicate for whatever reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Ambiguous step definitions" means that you have 2 or more steps with the same definition and so specflow doesn't know which one you are wanting to run.  Each step has to be unique.  In your case you have 2 identical Given statements that look like this:

```
 [Given(@"I navigate to the HomePage with (.*)")]
```

In two different classes.  Remove one of them and it should run.

Comment: Yes i know this. But i was trying to come up with a solution in which i didn't have to rename the same steps differently for all my test cases

Comment: you dont have to, it can read the steps in any step definition file. You only need 1 copy of the step definition to use it in any feature file

Comment: This worked! thank you :)